# Why return type class give trash value in operator overloading

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

**Use case (1):**
When we use return class type in assignment operator overloading  then i got trash values why ?

**Code of class return type**

```
   #include <iostream>
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    using std::string;
    
    class home
    {
    private:
        int home_N0;
        int rooms;
        string address;
    
    public:
        void set_data()
        {
            cout << "Enter Data Plz ...\n";
            cout << "Enter Address : " << endl;
            getline(cin, address);
            cout << "Enter Home Number : ";
            cin >> home_N0;
            cout << "Enter Room Number : ";
            cin >> rooms;
        }
    
        void show_data()
        {
            cout << "Home Number : " << home_N0 << endl;
            cout << "Room Number : " << rooms << endl;
            cout << "Address : " << address << endl;
        }
        home operator=(home obj)
        {
            home temp;
            cout << "Assigment opearator Invoke " << endl;
            temp.home_N0 = obj.home_N0;
            temp.address = obj.address;
            temp.rooms = obj.rooms;
            return temp;
        }
    };
    
    int main()
    {
        home h1, h2;
        h1.set_data();
        h1.show_data();
        h2 = h1;
        h2.show_data();
 return 0;
}
```

**Output**
output of this program is trash ! . means it can't copy any value but why ?

**Use case (2):**
When we use void return type not class then it was copy the values why ?

**Code of void return type**

```
  void  operator=(home obj)
    {
        // home temp;
        cout << "Assigment opearator Invoke " << endl;
        home_N0 = obj.home_N0;
        address = obj.address;
        rooms = obj.rooms;
        // return temp;
    }
};
```

**Output**
successfully copy all values but why ?

Comment: The significant difference is not the return type. If you change your first function to return `void`  and remove `return temp;`, it will still misbehave (and you can probably see why).

Comment: @molbdnilo : but  i don't know why it misbehave ? if return type is  not void!?

Comment: Consider `struct A { void f(int y); int x = 0; };`. Do you see the difference between `void A::f(int y) { x = y; }`  and `void A::f(int y) { A temp; temp.x = y; }`? If you do `A a; a.f(1);`, what is the value of `a.x` in each case?

Comment: To see that the return type is unimportant, change the first to return `void` and remove `return temp;`, then change the second to return `home` and add `return *this;`. Your problem will still be there.

Comment: @molbdnilo : *this  ... was worked but why ?

Comment: @molbdnilo: but i can't under stand why temp can not copy the obj values !?

Comment: `temp`*does* copy the values, but you never use `temp` after that. (Think about which object you're modifying and that, as I said, the function's return value doesn't matter.) I suspect that the point you're missing is that `operator=` is literally the thing that performs the "assignment"; `x = y;` is exactly the same as `x.operator=(y)`, and "operator=" is just a special name for a normal function. Nothing happens except that function call, and it does not return a value that should be assigned by some other mechanism.

Comment: @molbdnilo : then why void can do  this operation ?

Comment: For the fourth time: the return type doesn't matter – it could be `void`, or `int`, or `std::vector<std::string>`, or anything else and you would still see the same behaviour from both implementations. (I don't understand why you are convinced that the return type is important when you have even seen for yourself that it isn't.) The one that works modifies the object`*this` by assigning to its members. The one that doesn't work doesn't modify `*this` at all but creates a new object that gets thrown away. That's the difference.

Comment: @molbdnilo : i think if i return any object like temp it doesn't store any ware and the data will not copy bcz we copy data into `home temp`.